# compare text in 2 elements and hide the class if its true

Tags: jquery

how do i compare the two elements:

`<a class="MenuSelected" href="c-4-kayaks-canoes.aspx">Kayaks &amp; Canoes</a>`

and this:

`<div class=title>Kayaks &amp; Canoes</div>`

If it finds the text in `div.title` as the same then add css `display:none`

I am not sure what to try as its the text inside that i need comparing!
I **cant** hard code the string like in the example below.

`$("div.title:contains('John')").css("display", "none");`

Comment: Why just try it, you code seems ok, and you could just use `.hide` instead of `.css("display", "none")`.

Comment: because i have 30 items to compare and it doesnt make sense to hard code the string.

Comment: `$div1.text().toLowerCase() == $div2.text().toLowerCase()`? Might need to `$.trim()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.title:contains('" + $("a.MenuSelected").text() + "')").hide();
```

or, more explicit but also more versatile (for example it allows to do case-insensitive comparisons):

```
$("div.title")
.filter(function () {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == $("a.MenuSelected").text().toLowerCase();
})
.hide();
```

You could do `$.trim()` there as well, as @JaredFarrish suggests in the comments.

The `:contains` selector in comparison is case-sensitive and whitespace-sensitive, so it only selects exact matches.

Comment: I'd suggest `$.trim()` and `.toLowerCase()` as additions, as well.

Comment: I like the second except the requery, which could be detrimental performance-wise, and I suppose subject to one-to-many comparisons and possibly not valid without iterating the list in an outer scope. You're also missing the `()` on the first `$.text()`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yeah, I've fixed the missing parens already. I figure there are not that many links to check, so performance concerns can be thrown overboard in this case. For many hundred or thousand `div.title`s it will be beneficial to cache the value of `$("a.MenuSelected").text().toLowerCase()`, for a menu that has, like, 10 entries - not so much.

Comment: If it's a menu with ten `a.MenuSelected`, would that `$.text()` even work?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes. It returns the text of the first-in-document-order `a.MenuSelected`. A menu is unlikely to ever have more than one selected item, at least that's what I assumed here.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in certain cases, for a better understanding you should provide your relevant html code

```
if ($('a.MenuSelected').text() == $('div.title').text())
{
    $('div.title').hide(); //same as css disaplay: none
}
```

Comment: `.title` elements may have many different values, and I'm not sure what you'd get if you do that against a list of elements instead of just one.

Comment: You mean ones in which it's one-to-one comparisons? Kinda flimsy, and somewhat indicative within the question that we're talking about series `.title`s. But I could be wrong, who knows.

Comment: about 6-10, its code generated depending on the number of categories that i need to show.

Comment: @Super1 And for 6-10 you write "MANY" in capitals? That's not "many" at all. It's barely "a handful".

Comment: @Super1 "Many" itself is relative. A few million atoms are not many. A few million JavaScript objects are. No need to apologize, though.